# JavaScript not working on website

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I'm pretty new to coding, so this block of code is really bad.

I'm making a simple log in system really quick but now I've been sucked in and can't figure out whats wrong with my code. Help is greatly appreciated.

The username and password is "admin" (I know, it's bad, but this website won't be public).

HTML:

```js
function loginUser() {
  var usernameId;
  usernameId = document.getElementById("username1").value;
  if (usernameId == "admin") {
    window.location = "home.html";
  }
}
function loginPassword() {
  var passwordId;
  passwordId = document.getElementById("password1").value;
  if (passwordId == "admin") {
    loginUser();
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="login-form">
  <input type="text" name="username1" placeholder="username"/>
  <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="password"/>
  <button onClick="loginPassword()">login</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `name="username1"` and `name="password1"`, but you're then getting the elements with `getElementById()`. If so, you need to use the `id` attribute instead of the `name` attribute:

```js
function loginUser() {
  var usernameId;
  usernameId = document.getElementById("username1").value;
  if (usernameId == "admin") {
    window.location = "home.html";
  }
}
function loginPassword() {
  var passwordId;
  passwordId = document.getElementById("password1").value;
  if (passwordId == "admin") {
    loginUser();
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="login-form">
  <!--               v---- changed here       ---->
  <input type="text" id="username1" placeholder="username"/>
  <!--                   v---- and here       ---->
  <input type="password" id="password1" placeholder="password"/>
  <button onClick="loginPassword()">login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @Vatsal That's actually not true; HTML attributes (such as `onclick` in this case) are case insensitive, so `onclick` and `onClick` are equivalent.

Comment: That works and the if statement works but the `window.location` isn't working. Thanks though! :)